# Chair is uncomfortable, do I just have to get used to it?

Tags: ergonomics

Last Saturday I received a chair that is very very similar to [this one](https://secretlabchairs.ca/collections/omega-series#omega_2020-stealth) (it's funny - I can't find the one I bought and this was just a few days ago).

I've been sitting on it ever since and it feels comfortable most of the time, but when I try to stand up or stretch, the back of my legs feels painful.

Here's a picture:
[image: Picture of a person sitting in a chair, with their feet resting on box underneath a desk. The hamstrings are marked in red.]

The part in red is where it hurts when I try to stretch.

I contacted customer support and this is what they said:

> This is the first time we are hearing this but please be assured that I will do my best to assist and advise accordingly. While we are not certified doctors/health professionals, I can only advise that this might have occurred due to sitting habits such as leaning forward against their desks when seated, hence placing more pressure onto the underside of the thighs. ​Comfort is subjective and you may be facing this because you were transitioning from a softer chair to a firmer one. Please rest assured that as our chairs are designed to promote ergonomic health, and it will take some time to get used to.

I used to have a [Herman Miller Celle](https://www.hermanmiller.com/es_lac/products/seating/office-chairs/celle-chairs/) chair and I've never had this problem, nor do I believe I had bad posture before. Could this really be a matter of getting used to it?? It's the third day in a row that I wake up feeling pain on my legs...

Comment: The seat may press more on your thighs than you expect.  That may cut off blod supply and press nerves.  Would that explain what you feel?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i don't know, maybe. The only way I can explain it is that I can't stretch my legs as far as I used to.

Comment: Can you ask to get a chair like your old one instead?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen no, I bought this on my own. The old one is at the office.

Comment: Like mechanical keyboards, people buy racing/gaming chairs because they're popular, not because they're comfortable or better... These style chairs are designed to keep you in position while driving a car. Sitting on them for a long time at a PC is uncomfortable. You will get used to it over time, but really any any other office chair will be more comfortable than this.

Comment: @flexi I especially love the chairs that have a pair of holes to run shoulder harness straps though; I've yet to see one actually come with a racing harness to strap you tightly in place. OTOH I suspect anyone who's enough of a realism nut to want to be strapped down like that while driving a virtual car is probably going to buy an actual racing seat and use bare metal (the optional fabric cover/padding would make a real race car heavier and thus very marginally slower).  I've never sat in one of those, but can only imagine it's even less comfortable than a racing inspired wheelly chair.

Comment: Stay away from gaming chairs. They look cool but they are far from ergonomic. Get a herman miller or steelcase - you have only one backbone and it will not get better with age!

Comment: @Daniel aside from the issue that I mention, it has been very comfortable. The chair is adjustable in almost all the ways that my previous Herman Miller chair was. Do you have data to show that gaming chairs aren't ergonomic?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari A lot of test reviews and my own search for the perfect chair... for example secret lab is the only manufacturer of gaming chairs I know of who has adjustable lumbar support. Then the backrest is rigid as this comes with the design. A good office chair has adjustable pressure flexible backrest. Also the seat should pivot back and forth according to the position of the backrest and optimally be adjustable in depth - i think that is what´s causing your current problems. The headrest is not adjustable - great if you are the perfect height for this chair ... should I go on?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari and also I was talking about ergonomics, not adjustability. Maybe this chair fits you perfectly so you don´t need to adjust anything. Still does not mean its ergonomic.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari If you bought this on your own, I would suggest returning it and buy another you know you can sit comfortably in.  If this is for working at home, your employer may be able to help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think resting your feet on a box is not the best thing. You may subconsciously be firing your leg muscles continuously because your body is aware that your feet are not on a stable surface.

You should try lowering your chair so that your feet are on the ground.

Comment: Yeah the box is temporary until I get a proper footrest. If I lower the chair, then my arms won't be lined up with my desk :(. But i'll try this to see what happens, thanks.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari - Before you pack the chair to return it I would use an actual object designed to be a footrest.  I suspect that is indeed your problem.

Comment: as an interim solution you could try moving the box back so that it's supporting your heels instead of the front half of your foot.  The weight of your lower legs is going down to your heel; and with it unsupported other muscles have to tension to support the load and keep your feet level.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying this out now. I already feel a little bit less pain.

Comment: I agree with this answer, I was actually having pretty similar ergonomic issues. I since got a variable height desk and am able to lower it so that my feet are now firmly on the ground. Ergo issues have disappeared

Comment: Foot rests are generally angled rather than flat.  That would be a better solution.  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91ZcGX34jLL._AC_SL1500_.jpg

Comment: @numenor thank you for your answer! I feel a lot less pain now that I am resting my entire foot :)

Comment: I had a similar issue.  I was unconsciously firing my leg muscles to keep my feet in place and the chair from moving.  Once you get a new footrest sit in the chair and focus on 100% relaxation of your legs.  You may find that it pushes your chair back or rotates it slightly.  To fix this issue I had to get locking casters on my chair.

Comment: The box doesn't look sturdy enough to hold up the weight of two legs at full rest, which means you're probably constantly listing your legs up (partially), which keeps the muscle in use and thus will hurt after a long while.

Answer (score 4):

If your legs hurt then something is very wrong. It's most likely not your legs - seems unlikely that they would hurt - and more likely referred pain from your back, where your nerves are getting hurt.

So first off, if you end up needing to, then return the chair. Or throw it out - back pain is not worth 500 bucks.

Next up your posture is terrible - you should be sitting with far less hard right angles - your legs (thigh/shin) should be at ~100 degrees, and your torso/thigh should also be at ~100 degrees. This implies that you would be sitting with your thigh not perpendicular to the ground, but a line from your buttock to knee should be at a ten degree angle to the ground. You shouldn't feel like you are falling out the seat, but it should be a slight sensation of.

This puts more pressure on your feet, and reduces pressure on your low back.

Next, your feet should be totally, 100% supported - heels included. Just get some books and stack them up. Use something that can bear your whole weight - that looks like a tissue box! Your feet should feel like they can be at rest.

Answer (score 1):

> Chair is uncomfortable, do I just have to get used to it?

I would say no. While some ergonomic chairs take some time getting used to, because your muscles need to adjust to more "active" sitting, this does not seem to be the case here.

Your current chair consist basically of two fixed, straight planes. For longer periods of sitting, your chair should adjust to and support slight changes in your posture. This will prevent you getting constant pressure on any one specific spot, like stopping blood flow to your legs and keep your intervertebral disks engaged.

Your photo also shows an incorrect setup. Your feet should firmly touch the ground and your elbows should be able to rest comfortably on the desk surface. So you should probably also think about lowering your desk.

See [this link](https://www.posturite.co.uk/help-advice/useful-resources/learning-guides/art-of-sitting) for an example of a good setup and notice especially the difference in the lower spine.

Your Celle chair at work had a mechanism that changes the angle of the seat relative to the angle of the backrest. This way, when you lean forward the seat tilts forward also, relieving pressure on the underside of your thighs. It also had a somewhat flexible backrest to enable you to shift your weight and actively engage your back muscles while still supporting your back with an adjustable pressure.

[This video also gives some good tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ree1CWifQTg)